# Creating multiple forms without flooding the controller with new objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

How do I create multiple forms without having to create the object in the controller/load them by ajax?

Say you have a **Forum** model that has many **posts**, and each post has many **tags**. You are looking at a list of posts at `forms_controller#index`.

Say you want to allow the user to tag posts from the same template. One way is to load the form via a remote link when needed.

```
# forums/index.html
= link_to "Add Tag", new_post_tag_path, remote: true

# tags_controller.rb
def new
  @tag = @post.tags.build
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

# tags/new.js.erb
<%= j render("form") %>
```

But that requires going to the server and back again to render the form.

Another way is to create the object when looping over the posts.

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  = form_for @post.tags.build do
```

That doesn't work very well if you want to create several tags at the same time.

Is there another way to do this, perhaps with JS, without having to go to the server/or create the object as in the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates has done a great screencast on this subject.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2  Hopefully this should provide you with what you need.

Comment: Thank you, but I think that requires a trip to the server and back, does it not? Why if I want to add forms to the page without doing the round trip?